# Cannot find a differ supporting object template error - stacktrace doesn't show where it comes from

Tags: angular, ngfor, stack-trace, angular16

I'm writing an angular16 application and I encountered something that i don't understand, i see that i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe? Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG02200
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3117:31)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:3900:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:3931:9)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:3882:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:3832:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:13476:21)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13626:9)
    at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13569:13)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:13485:9)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13626:9)
```

so obviously I'm running an `*ngFor` on something that is not iterable, but where is the error ? the stack trace doesn't go to my code.

this is my `development` configuration flags in `angular.json`:

```
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
```

am i missing something? how can i see the origination of this error ?

Comment: Looks like you're iterating over an object and not an array. Do you have `    "angularCompilerOptions": { "strictTemplates": true, }` in your tsconfig ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - it's set to true, i don't care bout the error much, i just care to why i can't see my source code that caused it

Comment: Because the error isn't thrown by your code but a hook of `NgFor` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - yeah that's why, no way to show any debug info? it's a complex project with nested FormArrays so it looks as if i use FormGroup instead of FormControl somewhere but no idea where. if i could see the object that it can't find registgerOnChange before the error or something, i could pinpoint the location